# Softcon indipay module showing parameter missing exception for ccavenue gateway

Tags: php, laravel, payment-gateway, laravel-6, ccavenue

I have created controller named ccavenue and have passed static parameters as of now to check whether it lands on ccavaenue page. But I am not able to proceed to that step as "Missing parameter exception" is thrown.

Below is my controller

```
    class CcavenueController extends Controller
{
    public function ccavenuepayment(Request $request)
    {
        $parameters = [
            'merchant_id' => '11111',
            'currency' => 'INR',
            'redirect_url' => 'ddata/create',
            'cancel_url' => 'ddata/create',
            'language' => 'EN',
            'tid' => '1',
            'order_id' => 2222222,
            'amount' => 20000,
            'billing_full_name'=> 'xyz',
            'billing_email' => 'xyz@gmail.com',
            'billing_contact_number' => '9999999999',
            'billing_address' => 'xxx',
            'billing_city' => 'yyyy',
            'billing_state' => 'cccc',
            'billing_country' => 'India',
        ];
        $order = Indipay::prepare($parameters);
        return Indipay::process($order);
    }
}
```

The parameters get passed to prepare function as well but the same fails in checkparameter function.

I am not able to get where the actual issue lies.

Can someone help

Comment: Hello, Have you found any solution for the same? I am also facing same issue.